# Use Maps application in my Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, parameters, dictionary

I am currently developing an application which has a maps feature. My map is working, but I still need to create a Directions option. In previous versions of the Android SDK there used to be a class called DrivingDirections, which did exactly what I want. Now it's gone and I don't know how to add this feature to my current map. I read that Google have updated their terms thus making the use of Directions in apps kinda illegal or something like that. But there are Directions in my built-in Maps application. So my question is - Is there any way for me to pass parameters (longitude, latitude) from my application to the built-in application so that the built-in Maps can then draw the route from the start point to the end point?

P.S. I don't necessarily need this to be done by passing parameters. Any solution will be fine, as long as I can draw the route from point A to point B on my already displayed map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to pass
>   parameters (longitude, latitude) from
>   my application to the built-in
>   application so that the built-in Maps
>   can then draw the route from the start
>   point to the end point?

No, sorry, at least not through any published and documented mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/

or perhaps collaborating with these fine folks:

http://code.google.com/p/andnav/